# Selenium- Clicking a Checkbox by Label

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am writing code to test a webpage using Selenium in C#, and I need to click a checkbox with dynamically generated parameters. Here is a snippet of the html:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="2948" onclick="locBoxOnClick(this, 0);" name="locCombo2948">
  <label for="locCombo2948">
    AL          
    <br>
  </label>
```

I can find the label using XPath but when I try to actually click the box, nothing happens.

Code:

```
By.XPath("(//*[contains(text(), '" + appDto.StatePicker_SpecificCheckbox +     "')])").Click();
```

EDIT:
Finally solved it using a somewhat ghetto method but it works:

```
By.XPath(".//label[contains(text(), '" + appDto.StatePicker_SpecificCheckbox     + "')]/../input")
```

Basically you find the label, go to the parent node, then go to it's input child node. Hope this helps anyone else with this issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you're using wrong `xpath`, your provided `xpath` is locating `label` element while you need `input` element by using `label`, So you should try to select check box by using label text with below  xpath :-

```
appDto.StatePicker_SpecificCheckbox = "AL"

By.XPath(".//input[following-sibling::label[contains(., '" + appDto.StatePicker_SpecificCheckbox + "')]]").Click();
```

Comment: It returned a NullReferenceException when I tried, sadly :(

Comment: How did you try?? could you share please??

Comment: For the provided HTML it would be `driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//input[following-sibling::label[contains(., 'AL')]]")).Click();`

Comment: I tried that exact line of XPath that you suggested.

Comment: @JohnDoe2016 `FindElement` never throws `NullReferenceException`, might be issue in `appDto.StatePicker_SpecificCheckbox` where you setting value on this, check it...:)

Comment: Found a derp move by me lol. Getting a new error now though:

An exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.InvalidSelectorException' occurred in WebDriver.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression .//input[following-sibling::label[contains(., 'AL')]] because of the following error:

[object Error]

Comment: Just execute this `driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//input[following-sibling::label[contains(., 'AL')]]")).Click();` and let me know...:)

Comment: That's what I was executing. The error remains sadly :(

Comment: Ok once try as : `driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//label[contains(., 'AL')]/preceding-sibling::input")).Click();` and let me know..:)

Comment: Same error. I don't understand why these aren't working.

Comment: It does mean that error. I've been trying variations of the XPath but it keeps error-ing out.

Comment: Weird!!! Just for make sure open browser console by pressing f12 and execute this `$x(".//input[following-sibling::label[contains(., 'AL')]]")` and let me know.

Comment: It returned [ ] and nothing else

Comment: Did you tried it where check box present in the page or not??

Comment: I did execute it when the checkbox was present

Comment: And you are getting result `[]` at that page.Right??

Comment: Once also try this `$x("//label[contains(., 'AL')]/preceding-sibling::input")` if again same result make sure this element is not inside any frame or iframe...

Comment: It still returned [ ].  Also, I have already navigated successfully to the iframe that this element resides in, as I can manipulate other elements within the same iframe. At this point in execution, the program still is pointing to the appropriate iframe.

Comment: Oh man if it is inside an iframe you need to execute provided command within iframe document.. otherwise you will always get empty array.. that's the problem

Comment: Share your full code to click on check box and also share iframe HTML

Comment: You need to switch that iframe before finding element as `driver.SwitchTo().Frame("iframe name or id");` then execute `driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//label[contains(., 'AL')]/preceding-sibling::input")).Click();`

Answer (score 0):

There is a flaw in your HTML - the value of the `for` attribute of label [should reference an ID](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label#attr-for) (`locCombo2948`). However, the input does not have an ID, only name. Thus clicking on the label (as the your xPath selector targets actually the label, not the checkbox) it won't make any effect.

Don't know if you can fix the HTML. If not, you can simply click on the checkbox itself, using something like

```
By.CssSelector("input[name='locCombo2948']").Click()
```

Comment: I'd rather not have to do it this way because then I'd need a dictionary for every Location-ID combo

Answer (score 0):

Your XPath finds the `<label>` element, not the `<input>` element. In some browsers, this is not clickable. Try searching for the `<input>` element containing the `<label>` element:

```
//*[contains(text(), '" + appDto.StatePicker_SpecificCheckbox + "')]/ancestor::input
```

Comment: It returned a null reference exception, sadly :(

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you using this xpath:

```
string Xpath = $"//input[.//label[contains(.,{appDto.StatePicker_SpecificCheckbox})]]";
```

Hope it works with you :)